# Django 1.11.29. When sending long string on subject, Django inserts \t and extra space after comma

Tags: django, email, subject

Django 1.11.29. When sending long string on subject, Django inserts \t and extra space after comma. I tried sending emails setting to QP, 8bit. But Django if subject length is more than 70 chars, it inserts extra space and tabulation

```
From nobody Fri Jan 20 13:25:04 2023
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Subject: Earth - Earth population is  4, 652,
 123 people and digest is d3ea33dbe135a35fdde8984d1d920b8e6149526ed1fb5c9c656e8834d85d3a4e
From: me@me.com
To: me1@me.com
Date: Fri, 20 Jan 2023 13:25:04 -0000
Message-ID: <20230120132504.88256.54199@medet-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted printable
Subject: Earth - Earth population is  4, 652,
 123 people and digest is d3ea33dbe135a35fdde8984d1d920b8e6149526ed1fb5c9c656e8834d85d3a4e
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
MIME-Version: 1.0

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tem=
por incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Suscipit tellus mauris a d=
iam maecenas sed enim ut. In vitae turpis massa sed. Dictum varius duis at =
consectetur lorem. At volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate =
eu. Vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse. Lacus lao=
```

i've tested and tried a lot of things, but i dont know how to resolve to sending long subjects. I also checked and its not helps
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7747

i've tested and tried a lot of things, but i dont know how to resolve to sending long subjects. I also checked and its not helps
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7747